# Search Filter with Checkbox in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, next.js

```
const MemberSearchFilter = () => { 
const memberList = [{
    "member_id": "133",
    "name": "Deepak Ramnani",
    "checked": "false"
  },
  {
    "member_id": "116",
    "name": "Yash Chandhok",
    "checked": "false"
  },
  {
    "member_id": "115",
    "name": "Tonia Sehan",
    "checked": "false"
  },
  {
    "member_id": "101",
    "name": "Akanksha Garg",
    "checked": "false"
  },
 ]

const [getMemberList, setGetMemberList] = useState(memberList);
const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState("");

const onTypeFilterNonMemberHandler = (e) => {
    const textValue = e.target.value;
    console.log(e);
    if (textValue !== "") {
      const results = getMemberList.filter((customer) => {
        return customer.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(textValue.toLowerCase());
      });
      setGetMemberList(results);
    } else {
      setGetMemberList(memberList);
    }

    setSearchName(textValue);
  };

const checkedMember = [];
const onClickCheckboxHandler = (e) => {
    
    if (e.target.checked) {
      checkedMember.push(e.target.value);
    } else {
      const index = checkedMember.indexOf(parseInt(e.target.value));
      checkedMember.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };


return (
<>
<div className="col-md-9">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          className="form-control w-3/6"
                          style={{ width: "300px" }}
                          placeholder="search by name"
                          onChange={(e) => onTypeFilterNonMemberHandler(e)}
                        />
</div>
<div className="row">
                        {getMemberList.map((list, keys) => (
                          <>
                            <div className="col-md-12" key={keys}>
                              <div className="border my-[5px] rounded-lg px-[10px] py-[5px] relative">
                                <div className="flex align-center justify-center">
                                  <div className="specialist-infos w-100">
                                    <div>
                                      <h4
                                        className="xs:text-[13px] text-[15px]"
                                        style={{ color: "#702963" }}
                                      >
                                        {list.name}
                                      </h4>
                                      <p className="mb-0 text-[12px]">
                                        {list.current_organisation}
                                      </p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <input
                                    type="checked"
                                    name={`sendToMember`}
                                    className="radio_input"
                                    id={list.name}
                                    value={list.member_id}
                                    onChange={(e) => onClickCheckboxHandler(e)}
                                  />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </>
                        ))}
</div>
</>

}
```

In the above code. I want to search the members by using the search filter and also I want to implement the checkbox for the same,
Now the problem is onClickCheckboxHandler is working fine but when i search the members from my list by using onTypeFilterNonMemberHandler the checked box is not working, I don't understand where I'm making mistake please help me out.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem like the actual code, since `const` is misspelled and you've written `useState([memberList])` instead of `useState(memberList)`; do you mind sharing the code you have running?

Comment: yes this is not an actual code , i got the memberList from the api  after that using useState to intialize the value

Comment: You reformatted the code, but there's still quite a few issues with it, some of which may be causing your problem; you're using `radio` inputs instead of `checkbox` inputs; you reference `checkedMember`, which isn't mentioned before in the code; assuming that `checkedMember` is some sort of state, you mutate it directly instead of calling `setCheckedMember`...
As far as the root of the problem, I think your issue might be that the inputs are uncontrolled, and so they're not connected to the actual items in the rendered array. Reformat your code a bit more and let's see if this is the case ;)

Comment: @EvyatarShafran the code is updated please check and please help me out for the same

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this way. Is this what you want? If not, leave a comment

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const MemberSearchFilter = () => {
    const memberList = [
        {
            member_id: '133',
            name: 'Deepak Ramnani',
            checked: 'false',
        },
        {
            member_id: '116',
            name: 'Yash Chandhok',
            checked: 'false',
        },
        {
            member_id: '115',
            name: 'Tonia Sehan',
            checked: 'false',
        },
        {
            member_id: '101',
            name: 'Akanksha Garg',
            checked: 'false',
        },
    ];

    const [getMemberList, setGetMemberList] = useState(memberList);
    const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState('');
    const [checkedMember, setCheckedMember] = useState([]);

    const onTypeFilterNonMemberHandler = (e) => {
        const textValue = e.target.value;
        console.log(e);
        if (textValue !== '') {
            const results = getMemberList.filter((customer) => {
                return customer.name
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .startsWith(textValue.toLowerCase());
            });
            setGetMemberList(results);
        } else {
            setGetMemberList(memberList);
        }

        setSearchName(textValue);
    };

    const onClickCheckboxHandler = (e) => {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            setCheckedMember((prev) => prev.concat(e.target.value));
        } else {
            setCheckedMember((prev) =>
                prev.filter((item) => item !== e.target.value)
            );
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-md-9">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control w-3/6"
                    style={{ width: '300px' }}
                    placeholder="search by name"
                    onChange={(e) => onTypeFilterNonMemberHandler(e)}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                {getMemberList.map((list, keys) => (
                    <>
                        <div className="col-md-12" key={keys}>
                            <div className="border my-[5px] rounded-lg px-[10px] py-[5px] relative">
                                <div className="flex align-center justify-center">
                                    <div className="specialist-infos w-100">
                                        <div>
                                            <h4
                                                className="xs:text-[13px] text-[15px]"
                                                style={{ color: '#702963' }}
                                            >
                                                {list.name}
                                            </h4>
                                            <p className="mb-0 text-[12px]">
                                                {list.current_organisation}
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        name={`sendToMember`}
                                        checked={checkedMember.some(
                                            (item) => item === list.member_id
                                        )}
                                        className="radio_input"
                                        id={list.name}
                                        value={list.member_id}
                                        onChange={(e) =>
                                            onClickCheckboxHandler(e)
                                        }
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default MemberSearchFilter;
```